# Unable to load 'minutes' correctly from CSV into in Power Query / Pivot

Tags: excel, csv, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a folder of CSV files containing timestamps and parameter values.

My timestamps are formatted as follows:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

For example as below:

```
09/01/2023 11:17:40
```

In Excel 2019, I first load my Query Options and select the Regional Settings as 'English (United Kingdom)'. After this, I load my folder of CSV files and create a pivot table based on it.

For the most part, the pivot table works as expected and automatically converts my TimeStamp column to subgroups from Year to Seconds. However, at the Minute level it seems to fail, specifically as below. As evident from the picture, the Minute appears as `01`, yet looking at the timestamps below it there should be minute groups for the minutes `17`, `18`, `19`, ...

Instead, it seems as if the Minutes field gets the value of the Month.

I believe my date time structure matches the locale for English (United Kingdom), but something causes it to not work. Any suggestions?

Below is a subset CSV for testing/replication:

```
TimeStamp,BattTempMain,BatteryTotalChargeHV,BatteryTotalDischargeHV,BatteryVoltageHV,DistanceAccuracy,DistanceTotal,DistanceTrip,DistanceValid,EVSpeed,Fence1,Fence2,Fence3,Fence4,FenceCombined,FenceValid,IndoorTemp,Latitude,Longitude,Odometer,OutdoorTemp,Speed,SpeedAccuracy,SpeedValid,StateOfChargeBMS,GeofenceLocation,GeofenceStatus,Device,Meta
09/01/2023 11:17:40,18.0,500320.5802161523,505.7552105152147,377.0,,,,,0.0,,,,,,,18.6,,,1197.0,18.0,,,,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:17:45,18.0,500320.5799831355,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:17:50,18.0,500320.57986662706,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:17:55,18.0,500320.57963361026,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:00,18.0,500320.57951710187,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:05,18.0,500320.579284085,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:10,18.0,500320.5791675766,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:15,18.0,500320.5789345598,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:20,18.0,500320.5788180514,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:25,18.0,500320.5785850345,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:30,18.0,500320.57846852613,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:35,18.0,500320.57823550934,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:40,18.0,500320.57823550934,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:45,18.0,500320.57823550934,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:50,18.0,500320.57776947564,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:18:55,18.0,500320.57753645885,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:00,18.0,500320.57741995045,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:05,18.0,500320.5771869336,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:10,18.0,500320.5770704252,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:15,18.0,500320.57695391675,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:20,18.0,500320.57672089996,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:25,18.0,500320.57660439156,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:30,18.0,500320.5764878831,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:35,18.0,500320.5762548663,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:40,18.0,500320.5761383579,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:45,18.0,500320.57602184947,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:50,18.0,500320.5759053411,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:19:55,18.0,500320.5757888327,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:00,18.0,500320.5755558158,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:05,18.0,500320.57543930743,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:10,18.0,500320.57532279904,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:15,18.0,500320.5752062906,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:20,18.0,500320.5750897822,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:25,18.0,500320.5749732738,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:30,18.0,500320.57485676534,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:35,18.0,500320.57474025694,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:40,18.0,500320.57450724015,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:45,18.0,500320.5743907317,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:50,18.0,500320.5742742233,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:20:55,18.0,500320.5741577149,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:00,18.0,500320.5740412065,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:05,18.0,500320.57392469805,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:10,18.0,500320.57380818966,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:15,18.0,500320.57369168126,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.8,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:20,18.0,500320.5735751728,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:25,18.0,500320.5734586644,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:30,18.0,500320.573342156,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:35,18.0,500320.57310913916,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:40,18.0,500320.57299263077,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:45,18.0,500320.5728761224,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:50,18.0,500320.5727596139,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:21:55,18.0,500320.5726431055,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:00,18.0,500320.5725265971,505.7552105152147,377.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:05,18.0,500320.57241008873,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:10,18.0,500320.5722935803,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:15,18.0,500320.5721770719,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:20,18.0,500320.5720605635,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:25,18.0,500320.5719440551,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:30,18.0,500320.57182754664,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:35,18.0,500320.57171103824,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:40,18.0,500320.57159452984,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:45,18.0,500320.5714780214,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:50,18.0,500320.5712450046,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:22:55,18.0,500320.57089547935,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:00,18.0,500320.5704294457,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:05,18.0,500320.57007992046,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:10,18.0,500320.5696138868,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:15,18.0,500320.5691478532,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:20,18.0,500320.56879832793,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:25,18.0,500320.5683322943,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:30,18.0,500320.56786626065,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:35,18.0,500320.567400227,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:40,18.0,500320.56705070176,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:45,18.0,500320.5665846681,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:50,18.0,500320.5662351429,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:23:55,18.0,500320.56588561763,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:00,18.0,500320.5655360924,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:05,18.0,500320.56518656714,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:10,18.0,500320.56495355035,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:15,18.0,500320.5647205335,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:20,18.0,500320.5644875167,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:25,18.0,500320.56425449986,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:30,18.0,500320.56402148306,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:35,18.0,500320.5637884662,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:40,18.0,500320.5635554494,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:45,18.0,500320.5633224326,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:50,18.0,500320.5630894157,505.7552105152147,376.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:24:55,18.0,500320.56285639893,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:00,18.0,500320.5626233821,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:05,18.0,500320.5623903653,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:10,18.0,500320.56215734844,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:15,18.0,500320.5616913148,505.7552105152147,376.25,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,17.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:20,18.0,500320.56134178955,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
09/01/2023 11:25:25,18.0,500320.56134178955,505.7552105152147,376.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,56.153505,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,None,0,1F4F8F26,SkodaEnyaq
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to pull out hour, minute and date in the query?

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Hour", each Time.Hour([TimeStamp])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Minute", each Time.Minute([TimeStamp])),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Date", each Date.From([TimeStamp]))
```

[image]

Comment: I am not explicitly pulling those out - they are automatically generated by Excel in the pivot table when I drag in the "TimeStamp" field. I am able to 'manually' extract the correct date and time fields by adding custom columns, but I am trying to identify how to do this with minimal steps as part of a guide for a set of end users

Comment: I can in principle change the way the CSV files are generated to have a separate column for year, month, date, hour, minute, second. But I would prefer not to do so and instead let Excel correctly generate these from its interpretation of the timestamp. But as evident, it seems there is a problem at the Minutes level

Comment: While the issue shows up in the context of a pivot table, I assume it needs to be solved to some extent at the Power Query level in order to find a consistent solution that will allow the pivot table to correctly display the Minutes